# Problem with abstracts in the jams-l document class

Tags: titles, abstract, amsart

I am preparing a submission to the Journal of the American Mathematical Society, and I'm using the `jams-l` document class. However, the abstract always appears after the body of my article text. Anyone knows how to move the abstract to the front, or am I doing something wrong? Here's some sample code where it happens. Sorry for the long code but I tried to not to delete anything that might have caused it. To load it, one needs the [`jams-l.cls` package](http://www.ams.org/publications/journals/journalsframework/jamsauthorpac).

```
\documentclass{jams-l}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{xca}[theorem]{Exercise}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\title{}
\author{}
\address{}
\curraddr{}
\email{}
\thanks{}

\author{}
\address{}
\curraddr{}
\email{}
\thanks{}

\subjclass[2010]{Primary }

\date{}

\dedicatory{}

\begin{abstract}
abstract abstract abstract
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

text of article text of article text of article

\bibliographystyle{amsplain}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: If they require that class, then don't worry: a comment in the class file is "Set abstract at the end of the paper instead of the topmatter section"

Comment: aha... didn't spot that, thanks for the answer! Now it's changed from a worry to a minor irritation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A comment in the class file says

```
% Set abstract at the end of the paper instead of the topmatter section
```

This means that the abstract at the end is what the staff at the Journal of AMS wants it to be. Since you're required to use that class, leave the abstract where *they* want it to appear.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I didn't read the class file (was I supposed to? haha). I thought I did something wrong but I guess it's alright now.